# Conditionally require fields within a directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of credit cards which the user can choose to edit. The credit card form is bound to the list and the form is shown if they select edit on a given card. The credit card form is a custom directive. The user can also add a new card. The usual fields are required if the credit card form is visible, but should not be required/validated if it's not visible. Visibility is managed with ng-show.

Here is the simplified version of the directive usage. The directive itself is as simple as you'd expect.

```
<div data-ng-repeat="profile in paymentProfiles" data-ng-show="profile.PaymentProfileGuid == SelectedPaymentProfile && options.enableCreditCardEdit">
    <creditcard-widget title="Enter your Card Information" 
          card="profile" isrequired="profile.PaymentProfileGuid == SelectedPaymentProfile && options.enableCreditCardEdit"></creditcard-widget>
</div>
```

I've tried binding the isrequired in two-way, one-way, and text. It only works as text and only if I pass a value instead of an expression. How can I pass a flag to a directive that is at least one-way data bound?

**EDIT**
I've tried passing the param with "@", "&", and "=". I'm trying to reduce things enough to post a jsfiddle or plukr link.
Here is the directive js:

```
.directive('creditcardWidget', function () {
    return {
        controller: 'CreditcardWidgetController',
        restrict: 'E, A',
        templateUrl: '/app/views/partials/creditcardWidget.html',
        scope: {
            card: "=card",
            types: "=",
            months: "=months",
            years: "=years",
            title: "@",
            opt: "&",
            prefix: "@",
            isrequired: "&"
        }
    };
});
```

**EDIT 2**

Here is a simplified [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/6FyVkB?p=preview)

Comment: Hi! Any chance you can replicate your code into an example on either jsFiddle or Plunkr?

Comment: You should show your directive code I believe you'll need to do something with the isolate scope using @, &, or = to get the appropriate behavior. = will create a two way binding & will allow a function on the scope of the "assigner" or @ will pass a value as a string one way (from how I understand them).  http://www.egghead.io/video/O9iVkfQJauQ < other videos here as well related to the other options here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/2ZFnd/) that uses `&`.  See what is different from what you have.

```
app.directive('creditcardWidget', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: '<div>isrequired={{isrequired()}}</div>',
        scope: {
            // ...
            isrequired: "&"
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log('link: isrequired=', scope.isrequired());
        }
    };
});
```

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.paymentProfiles = [
       { PaymentProfileGuid: 22}
    ];
    $scope.SelectedPaymentProfile = 22;
    $scope.options = {enableCreditCardEdit: true};
}
```

Comment: I think the 2 things I need to do are: 1) use "&", and 2) treat it like a function by using "()". Doing that in my simple plnkr seems to solve the problem. I'll double check before marking answered.